# Topic models in a structured document? (or would EM or MCMC work?)

Tags: statistics, probability, bayesian, montecarlo, topic-modeling

I have a set of documents that each consist of N words. The ith word of each document is selected from a common set of words, Wi={wi1, wi2, wi3, wi4}.

For example, the first word in each document might be selected from: {'alpha', 'one', 'first', 'lowest'}. The second word might be selected from: {'beta', 'two', 'second', 'lower'}. And so on.

These words may belong to different topics. For example, one topic might consist of {'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', etc...}. Another topic might be {'alpha', 'two', 'third', etc...}. Each document has a different topic usage (just like a normal topic model).

To generate a new document, you go through each position 1...N. For the ith word, you select a topic based on the document's topic usage, then select a word from Wi based on the topic's word usage. Therefore, each topic will have N total words - one for each position.

My question is how do I learn the latent parameters in this model? Specifically, I want to know (1) the topic usage of each document, and (2) the word composition of each topic. This looks very similar to a topic model, but I don't know if I can use anything out of the box?

Because I can write out the likelihood of the data given the parameters, I tried implementing an EM algorithm to estimate (1) topic usage, then use this to update (2) word usage (and keep iterating until convergence). However, this was really really slow.

Another thing I have read is if I can write the joint density function, I can try sampling from the posterior density to learn these hidden parameters (using MCMC). Does this sound feasible? I have ~100 documents, each document is ~1000 words long, and at each word position, you can select from 6 words.

If anyone can help or give advice, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: There's no programming question here. Would recommend you ask on http://crossvalidated.com

Answer (score 1):

Pure EM doesn't work for topic models: you need to use variational EM, as demonstrated in [the original Blei et al paper](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/BleiNJ03.pdf). The other way to do inference is to use a collapsed Gibbs' sampler, as described by Griffiths' et al's [Finding Scientific Topics](http://psiexp.ss.uci.edu/research/papers/sciencetopics.pdf) paper (and many others too).

Can you clarify the generative process? Are you saying you draw from a different topic for each position i (standard LDA)? That you want a different set of topics for position i than position i+1? That knowing the topic assignment for position i means you know the assignment for i+1..n? If you could write it out as a standard generative model then figuring out how to do inference should be pretty straightforward (and I'd be happy to edit my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You don't explicitly state this, but it looks implicit in your 4th paragraph:  Given the topic, the distribution for which word is chosen for the i'th slot is independent of the words that have (or will be) selected for the other slots.

If this is a case, then your model is (conforms to) a [Naive Bayesian Classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier), and that is probably your best bet; this type of model can be configured with one pass through the training data, and should be much better than using the EM algorithm.

If you have correlations between the words, given the class, you may want to look into "Tree-Augmented Bayesian Classifiers".

Comment: It's not naive Bayes because the topic assignments are latent. If you knew which words belonged to which topics max-likelihood estimation would be trivial.